# Do function with a fast decaying tails have an oscillating Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have observed that the Fourier transform of functions that have fast decaying tails has oscillations.

The most extreme example would be a square function. However, I have also observed this for functions $e^{-|x|^k}$ for $k>2$.

**My question:** Is there a theorem in Fourier analysis that somehow quatifies this observation?

Comment: The premise is not at all universally correct. For example, Gaussians $f(x)=e^{-a x^2}$ with $a>0$ have Fourier transform a constant multiple of $e^{-{1\over a}x^2}$. Similarly, $H(x)\cdot e^{-x^2/2}$ with $H$ a Hermite polynomial is an eigenfunction for Fourier transform, but oscillates only finitely-many times. What other examples were you thinking of?

Comment: @paulgarrett Yes, that is why I specified that $k>2$. But the class of $e^{-|x|^k}, k>2$ was the one I had in mind. Are you aware of any such results in Fourier theory?

Comment: I guess then also you want $k$ to _not_ be a positive even integer, otherwise the behavior is different. But, no, I do not know of such a pattern as  you speculate upon.

Comment: @paulgarrett Why do we want $k$ to be even? I think we still get oscillations for $k=3$ and $4$ for example.

Comment: For $k$ a positive even integer, $|x|^k$ is smooth at $0$, otherwise not. That is certainly a qualitative difference: local non-smoothness will have a strong effect on the decay rate of the Fourier transform, etc. That's all I meant to refer to.

Comment: @paulgarrett  Did not think about this. Thank you.